# Using a variable for the title argument in InputBox

Tags: excel, vba, variables, inputbox

I've created an InputBox which asks the user for the letter of the last column containing entries.  I'd like the title to be sheet name, according to an index.  Here's the code I've written:

```
Dim LastEntryCol As String  
Dim ShtName As Variant  
Set ShtName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2) '****The number 2 will need to be changed to an index.  For now it's hard-entered.  
LastEntryCol = Application.InputBox("What is the letter of the last column containing entry labels?", ShtName)`
```

When I run it, I get error 1004 "Method 'InputBox' of object '_Application' failed".  I suspect it has something to do with how I set ShtName, as the code runs properly if I replace the title argument with something like "hooray coding!"

Can anyone explain to me what's going wrong and how I can fix it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the whole `WorkSheet object`, instead of just its name. Try this:

```
Dim LastEntryCol As String
Dim ShtName As String
ShtName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name '****The number 2 will need to be changed to an index.  For now it's hard-entered.
LastEntryCol = Application.InputBox("What is the letter of the last column containing entry labels?", ShtName)
```

Comment: Perfect!  And thanks very much for explaining what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Sheets is a Collection so to get the name you need to use

```
ShtName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(2).Name
```

Also pretty sure this will always be a string so you could use `Dim ShtName As String` and avoid Set.

Comment: The OP is rightly using Set because you need it to assign a new object (a WorkSheet in this case) to a variable. Now (with your proposal or with mine, which are the same), you are just assigning a value to a String variable (or to a Variant variable, understood as string) and thus you CANNOT use Set (you have to delete it; your code triggers an error).

Comment: Yes that's why I stated he could avoid using set by specifying the data type as a String and using the Name Property. Although I forgot VBA Collections Item is implied by using the index as in your example.

Comment: No, you don't need to declare the variable as string. As said, your code (= used as variant) triggers an error. "Set" is not because of the variant/string type, but because of assigning a new object to a variable. A string value is not a new object, but a value and thus you CANNOT use Set with it.

Comment: Sorry just realized what you were referring to didn't realize I left that in there. Editted

Comment: No problem; just here to help :)

Comment: Thank you both for discussing this further. It's very informative for me!